# How to specify a 404 page using React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation for my React App. I am failing an SEO check for not providing a custom 404 page. I do not see anywhere in the [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) how to specify a 404 page, and I am unable to find any answers via searching. Right now, if a user visits an invalid route, it just brings them to the homepage. Is there someone more familiar with React Navigation that knows how to do this.